# GITHUB Push issue

Tags: github, push, branch

I am trying to push the code from one repository (let say XXX)to a specific branch(aaa) which is located in another repository(YYY). Is that possible. If so will you share the github commands here

Comment: You cannot push from one repository to the other. At least, not that i know of.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` takes 2 arguments - the name of the remote repository, and the branch to push to. This usually defaults to `origin master` but can be changed.

Assuming you are in branch `foo` in your local repo (`XXX`) and want to push to your remote repo (`YYY`) to a branch called `bar`:

Start by adding the remote repository to your local repo:

```
git remote add YYY https://github.com/Aarthi/YYY
```

Then check out the local branch you want to push (`foo`):

```
git checkout foo
```

then push this branch to the remote as `bar`:

```
git push YYY bar
```

Comment: This is the error am getting.error: src refspec Seating_testing does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@